# Access unmatch query

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I am trying to do an unmatch query in access: In Table 1 I have three columns

```
ID            q ID       Amt

1234411       999        5.00

1234411       996        -10.00

1234411       998        6.00
```

In the Table 2 I have two columns

```
ID                    amt

1234411              1.00
```

I need to make a query where it would look for an unmatch query by subtotaling the amt in Table 1 for similar ID number and compare it to Table 2. There would be multiple different ID in Table 1 and Table 2 with different amounts.

Optional Information:
What have you tried so far?: I have tried the simple unmatch query in Access but that does not work for this

Comment: Do you need the unmatched ones from table1 or table2?

Comment: You need to get the sum of your table 1 for each id number then unmatch it with your table 2.

Comment: is it possible for T1 to have an ID not in T2 or vice-versa? (i.e. is it only the difference in summed amounts that matters?)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.ID, Sum(T1.Amt) AS SumAmt 
FROM Table1 AS T1 
WHERE Sum(T1.Amt) <> 
  (
    SELECT SUM(t2.amt) 
    FROM Table2 AS T2 
    WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID
  )
GROUP BY T1.ID
```